# Kotlin generic bounds

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, mvp

I'm trying to port my MVP solution from JAVA to Kotlin and I have a big problem with generics. This is how my JAVA classes look like:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity<P extends BasePresenter> extends AppCompatActivity implements BaseView 

public abstract class BasePresenter<V extends BaseView>

public interface BaseView
```

And ported to Kotlin:

```
abstract class BaseActivity<P : BasePresenter<BaseView>> : AppCompatActivity(), BaseView 

abstract class BasePresenter<V : BaseView> 

interface BaseView
```

And when I'm trying to use

```
class MainActivity() : MainView, BaseActivity<MainPresenter>()
```

I'm getting "Type argument is not within its bounds. Expected: **BasePresenter**, **Found MainPresenter**"

Comment: Did you solved this problem? In presenter I have method attachView(view:V) and I have conflicts with this method if I try variants below. Let me know please if you tackle this problem. Thank you.

Comment: @RamanBranavitski please check my repo,
 (https://github.com/GDGWroclaw/Toast/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/droidsonroids/toast/common/mvp/MvpActivity.kt , if something is still unclear just let me know.

Comment: This repo does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The **Java** `class BaseActivity` states that `P` extends `BasePresenter<?>` whereas the **Kotlin** version states `BasePresenter<BaseView>` which obviously are not compatible.

To resolve that you can either relax the `BaseActivity` type parameter `P` like so:

```
abstract class BaseActivity<P : BasePresenter<*>>
```

or if you wish to have more type checking done by compiler you can specify type parameter for `view` like so:

```
abstract class BaseActivity<TPresenter : BasePresenter<TView>, TView : BaseView> : AppCompatActivity(), BaseView
```

And then use it as:

```
class MainPresenter : BasePresenter<MainView>()
class MainActivity() : MainView, BaseActivity<MainPresenter, MainView>()
```

Comment: In presenter I have method attachView(view:V) and I have conflicts with this method if I try your variants.

Type mismatch: inferred type is BaseMvpActivity<P, T> but T was expected

Comment: Look at post below please

Comment: I'm having same issue. Was this fixed anywhere?

Comment: Excelente, gracias. Thanks, arigato :)

The secret is using the <*> in BaseActivity class on BasePresenter...